# mongodb date storage in MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: java, mongodb

i am trying to store date in mm/dd/YYYY format to achieve that i tried following things in mongoShell

```
dt=new Date(2012,01,01)
ISODate("2012-01-31T18:30:00Z")
```

which is not my desirable format. I am trying to store it as ISODate("2012-01-01") so that i can use between , greater than less than kind of comparison to fetch my desirable data from mongoDB.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself: "i am trying to store date in mm/dd/YYYY format" and "I am trying to store it as ISODate("2012-01-01")" - which is it? (And why on earth would you *want* to store it as `mm/dd/YYYY`)? Surely you shouldn't care, so long as you can extract the data correctly - if the ISO format is more efficient (which it will be, vastly, for comparisons) then why not use that?

Comment: Dates in MongoDB are internally stored as UNIX timestamps; it doesn't matter if you create them using `Date` or `ISODate` (cc @JonSkeet) . You can change how a date is formatted, but under the covers it's the same thing. See: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dates

Comment: @NullUserException: Ah, that's good to know. I was fearing that Mongo would be one of these databases which had no *concept* of date/time at the storage level, and everything just used strings. That said, I still think `mm/dd/yyyy` is a bizarre format to use, rife with potential problems :)

Comment: @JonSkeet..actually i'm new to mongodb and my business requirement was like that okay...lets see what to do..thanks

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to store in the below format

```
{
  year : 2016,
  month: 1,
  day: 1,
  yymmdd : 20160001
}
{
  year : 2015,
  month: 10,
  day: 20,
  yymmdd : 20151020
}
```

**yymmdd** is
year multiplied by 10,000
month multiplied by 100 and added with date

So Jan - 1 2016 would be 2016x10000 + 0x100 +1 = 20160001
Nov-20  2015 would be 2015x10000 + 10*100 + 25 = 20151025

and so forth

The above design would enable sorting from 0AD to 9999AD

Date is a 64bit integer, so if you are using the yyyymmdd style(as above) its a 32bit integer, saves your space and serves your purpose

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your question is about how to convert the ISO date that you store in Mongo into a string.  I'm sure you can work out the proper syntax for Java, but in Mongo shell you can do it simply like this:

```
> d=new Date(2012,01,01)
ISODate("2012-02-01T05:00:00Z")
> print ( d.getFullYear()+"/"+d.getMonth()+"/"+d.getDate() )
2012/1/1
```

But note that you get back the number you passed to Date and not the number reflecting the month it is.  To solve that you can use `d.toLocaleDateString()`

```
> d.toLocaleDateString()
02/01/2012
```

This is because JavaScript Date function takes (and returns) 0-based months and you also want to make sure you are careful about the timezone relative to UTC/GMT time zone.